# Accessing the database and sending an email in a symfony batch script

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, propel

I am running Symfony 1.3.2 on Ubuntu. I need to write a batch script that can:

- Access the database using the ORM
- Send email(s)

IIRC, this was in a previous cookback, but I thing that was for an earlier version of Symfony (the API may have changed since).

Does anyone know how I may access the database via the ORM layer in a batch script and also how to send out email(s) in a batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also [Sending email from a task](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/04-Emails#chapter_04_sending_an_email_from_a_task) in the "More with symfony" book.

If you get your task working, you can [run it from cron](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line#chapter_13_bonus_round_using_tasks_with_a_crontab) or the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, put this at the top of your script:

```
require_once('/... ABSOLUTE_PATH...../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
```

... and change the ABSOLUTE_PATH to the absolute path to the ProjectConguration class. Works for a batch script and allows use of ORM. Haven't tested with the standard Symfony SwiftMailer but assume would be fine.

The settings "frontend" and "prod" and "false" and app/environment-specific. You can read more about them in the Symfony API documentation.